# Angular unit testing multiple getters on a singular service

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

So I'm trying to test the calls that *component x* make to it's injected service, the service it self has a couple of methods, and rxjs BehaviourSubject getters/setters.

Currently testing one getter like so.

```
let component: EditFeatureComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditFeatureComponent>;
  let vectorLayerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  let mockAnnoService = { getLayerToEdit: vectorLayerSubject.asObservable() };
  let mockFeatureService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getFeatureToEdit', 'setFeatureToEdit']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EditFeatureComponent, CoreMapComponent, MapsComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: AnnotationService, useValue: mockAnnoService},
        { provide: FeatureStyleService, useValue: mockFeatureService}
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Fields required for the component
    layer = {
      layerName: 'testLayer',
      ol_uid: 1
    }
    // Create the testbed
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFeatureComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('Should return a layer object and have a ol_uid of 1', fakeAsync(()=>{
    vectorLayerSubject.next(layer);
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.layer).toBe(layer);
  }))
```

And this works fine passes and covers code coverage, but how do I go about testing the other getter calls on the service and methods, as I can't have more than one mockValue assigned to a service.

Normally I would just create spyObj for the methods, but I can't seem to assign more than useValue to the service or store all the getters/methods in one variable.

I should also note that services are private and readonly on the component.

Comment: You can add multiple properties to mock object or could also implement mock Class with all the properties and register it using `useClass`.

Comment: How are you attempting to store the getters/setters? If you're mocking, you should be able to recreate the entire object if needed. That being said, I don't think you need to mock at all, just spy on the actual service methods.

+1 for Amit's "useClass"

Comment: Also I can't spy on the get methods, I tried to spy on them and was being thrown cannot find method of 'x' the get aren't actually methods.  get getFeatureLayer(){ return this.behaviorSubjectFeatureLayer }

Comment: Okay I think I see what you're getting at with setting multiple properties on one mock object I shall give that a shot.

Comment: @Munerz To spy on getter/setter methods use `spyOnProperty(obj, 'propName', 'get')`